# Узнать цвет пикселя в реальном времени с экрана

Tags: python, opencv

Мне надо узнать цвет любого пикселя (допустим в хроме) и к примеру вывести его (256.256.256). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Как вариант делать [временные скриншоты нужной области](http://robotday.ru/2018/12/27/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-python/)

Comment: 256 не бывает! 

Answer (score 0):

У Python есть библиотека (PIL) python imaging library, в библиотеке есть метод getpixel(). Думаю начать нужно с этого.